# ArrayList of arrayLists predicate method error

Tags: java, arraylist, predicate

Am having an implementation of ArrayList of arrayLists and trying to write an Predicate implementation for the same.

Please find my below code.

Pojo class `Menu.java`

```
public class Menu {
  private String name;
  private String code;


private ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>  childMenus = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>();
private ArrayList<Menu> Defaults = new ArrayList<Menu>();

  public boolean hasChildMenus() {

        childMenus.add(Defaults); 

    return childMenus != null && !childMenus.isEmpty();
  }
```

Am writting the below implementation in another class.**Updated Predicate method**

```
    private Predicate<? super Menu> byRoleAndPermissions(final Role role, final Set<String> permissionsSet) {

    return new Predicate<Menu>() {
      @Override
      public boolean apply(Menu menu) {
        final boolean filterForExternalUser = !role.isRoleInternal() && !menu.isVisibleToExternal() && !(role.getCode().equals("DLR_ADMN") && menu.getCode().equals("MDFY_USER_PRVG"));
        // for dealer and dealer read only related changes : MDFY_USER_PRVG
        if(!role.isRoleInternal() && (role.getCode().equals("DLR") || role.getCode().equals("DLR_RD_ONLY")) && menu.getCode().equals("MDFY_USER_PRVG")){
             return true;
        }
        if (filterForExternalUser) {
          return false;
        }
        SetView<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(menu.getPermissions(), permissionsSet);
        if (intersection.size() == 0) {
          return false;
        }
        if (menu.hasChildMenus()) {
                    menu.setChildMenus(new ArrayList<Menu>(filter(menu.getChildMenus(), byRoleAndPermissions(role, permissionsSet))));
        }
        return true;
      }
    };
  }
```

and am getting the below errors

```
Multiple markers at this line
            - The method filter(Collection<E>, Predicate<? super E>) in the type Collections2 is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>, Predicate<capture#4-of ? super 
             Menu>)
            - The method setChildMenus(ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>) in the type Menu is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Menu>)
```

how can i make it working for ArrayList of arrayLists implementation

**Update 1**

Am trying this implementation for adding menu bars with menus. like below design.

```
Admin (mainMenu)
- User
- Role
- Default
  - System Default
- Exit
```

This is the kind of implementation that am trying.

**Update 2**

I have modified the line in `Predicate` method as below :

```
menu.setChildMenus(new ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>(filter(menu.getChildMenus(), byRoleAndPermissions(role, permissionsSet))));
```

but now am getting the error :

```
Error : The method filter(Collection<E>, Predicate<? super E>) in the type Collections2 is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>, Predicate<capture#4-of ? super Menu>)
```

Comment: Whaat is *filter* and you haven't shown us *setChildMenus*

Comment: Btw, your `hasChildMenus` method will always return true (and it keeps on growing in size)

Comment: @user7 - i have updated my question with my design that what am trying. Please tell me., if you need more information

Comment: The goal of a predicate is to return true or false. A predicate that always returns true doesn't make much sense. And a predicate shouldn't have side-effects either. Just like a method called `hasChildMenus()` shouldn't add an element to a list. Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @user7 - `hasChildMenus` will always return true. only `Defaults` arrayList will happen occationally ( not always)

Comment: Your update is not that helpful. As JB Nizet pointed out, your Predicate must be side-effect free. In that standpoint, this is not a good design

Comment: Any suggestion for my implementation. am trying to make the `Menus` in java. once its all set with `menus`. Finally i can iterate in `html` and display in UI. This is am trying.

Comment: @user7 - I have update my `Predicate` method and now its not returning always `true`. But, am not sure how to implement for `ArrayList of arrayLists`